# Scanf input for char works once then is blank

Tags: c, scanf

I want to reference the input of `name` throughout the code I am writing, but for some reason after I use it successfully in the first `printf()`, the second `printf()` does not print the name.

```
int main()
{
    char name[50]; 
    char q1[1];
    printf( " What is your name?\n");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf( " Hi %s, Do you want to have some fun? [Y/N]\n",name);
    scanf("%s",q1);

    if(strcmp(q1,"Y") == 0||strcmp(q1,"y")==0)
    {
        printf("Awesome, let's play!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Fine"); goto endgame;
    }
    printf( "So %s, it's time to get started\n", name);
    endgame:
        getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The output for the entry 'Nick' is:

> Hi Nick, do you want to have some fun?
>  Awesome let's play
>  So ,
>   let's get started

I would expect it to say:

> So Nick, let's get started.

but for some reason char `name` is blank after it is used correctly the first time.

Comment: what is `q1`, exactly?

Comment: `scanf("%s", name);` --> `scanf("%49s", name);`

Comment: I added `char q1[50];` and it is working for me.

Comment: @moffeltje I think the other way (assumption), `q1` is a `char` only and the `%s` and `strcmp()` creates the issue. But then, what do we know? :-(

Comment: `char q1[1];` is too short for "Y"... you need room for the null

Comment: The if statement for q1 is just supposed to get the user to enter Y or N to move to the next section.

Comment: If the compiler placed `q1` right before `name`, then when you scan "Y" into `q1` the null could spill into the first char of `name`, which would become an empty string.

Comment: Ah @Dmitri. I did not know the q1[1] was too short, boosting that fixed the issue. Thanks

Comment: Rather than try to get `scanf()` to work well, consider using `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`.

Comment: when calling scanf() with a %s format specifier, always limit the length of input (one way: scanf( "%49s", name);)  (note length is one less than actual input buffer length to allow room for the trailing '\0' that scanf/%s will append.)  always check the return code from scanf() (in this case ==1) to assure the operation was successful.   '%s' will stop when it encounters any white space (like the newline) so when two successive scanf/%s are used, follow the first scanf with something like: while(int temp = getchar() && temp != '\n');   to consume the newline

Answer (score 4):

The problem, (*as I assumed correctly*) is with `char q1[1];` and then using it like

```
 scanf("%s",q1);
```

It is causing memory boundary overrun, because, a one-char array is not sufficient to hold a *string* of having only one element, as it lacks the space for the null-terminator required for the *string*. This invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Instead,

- change `char q1[1];` to `char q1;`
- change `scanf("%s",q1);` to `scanf(" %c", &q1);`
- change `if(strcmp(q1,"Y") == 0||strcmp(q1,"y")==0)` to `if((q1 =='Y') || q1 == 'y')`

That said, as a note,

1. The recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.
2. To avoid the possibility of buffer overflow by *longer* input(s), it's better to limit the length of the input with `scanf()` by writing like

   ```
   scanf("%49s", name);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Expand the size of your `q1` buffer. `scanf("%s", q1)` doesn't have enough room to store the input. Remember that C uses a null character `'\0'` to terminate strings. If you don't account for that, the buffer could overrun into other memory causing [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). In this instance, it's probably overwriting memory allocated to `name`, so `name` ends up pointing to "\0ick". This causes `printf(%s)`, which looks for `'\0'` to know when to stop printing, to think that the string is shorter than it really is.

The code works perfectly if you expand the buffer:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char name[50];
    char q1[50];
    printf( " What is your name?\n");
    scanf("%49s", name);
    printf( " Hi %s, Do you want to have some fun? [Y/N]\n",name);
    scanf("%49s",q1);

    if(strcmp(q1,"Y") == 0||strcmp(q1,"y")==0)
    {
        printf("Awesome, let's play!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Fine");
    }
    printf( "So %s, it's time to get started\n", name);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 What is your name?
Nick
 Hi Nick, Do you want to have some fun? [Y/N]
y
Awesome, let's play!
So Nick, it's time to get started
```

Note that I've added the qualifier `%49s` to avoid buffer overruns like this.

---

You could also circumvent the need for another string entirely by changing `char q1[50]` and `scanf("%49s")`  to simply `char q1` and `scanf("%c%*c", &q1)` (note the "address of" operator because `q1` is no longer a pointer).

You'll probably even get a performance gain from this (albeit small), because strings are notorious memory hoggers. Comparing a single character is usually preferred over comparing strings.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char name[50];
    char q1;
    printf( " What is your name?\n");
    scanf("%49s%*c", name);
    printf( " Hi %s, Do you want to have some fun? [Y/N]\n",name);
    scanf("%c%*c",&q1);

    if(q1 == 'Y' || q1 == 'y')
    {
        printf("Awesome, let's play!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Fine");
    }
    printf( "So %s, it's time to get started\n", name);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
    if(q1 == 'Y' || q1 == 'y')
    {
        printf("Awesome, let's play!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Fine");
    }
    printf( "So %s, it's time to get started\n", name);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

If you go this route, you have to ignore the enter key using the format specifier `%*c` because pressing enter sends a key to the stream as well.